# Force unique varchar(255) column value in a SQL Server table with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

I have database records for some users on a Windows server. One of the columns is the user's SID (unique string for that user).

When I get a message for a user, I want to first perform a query for a record with the SID value for the SID column. If no record is returned, then create a record with that SID value. However, between the query and the add, another thread can get a message with the same user/SID. So I could end up adding it twice.

1. Is there a way to create a transaction where no other record can be added to the table until the transaction completes?
2. Or is there a better way as locking an entire table, because no matter how fast the query/add, that's a choke point. (If this is the best way, I can query with no transaction, return if it exists, and only in the rare case it does not, then transaction, query again, add.)
3. Is there a way to tell SQL Server that the column is unique? The properties for setting that are disabled in SQL Server Management Studio, I assume because it's a `varchar`.

thanks - dave

Comment: Just execute `ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_YourTable_YourColumnName UNIQUE(YourColumnName)` and you're done in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a Unique Index on the column to enforce uniquenss of the values on the column and the you can use the following Code tweak it to your database specifications,
**Warring** Since I have set Transaction Isolation Level to SERIALIZABLE it can slow down the query if multipule users try to ADD the data since it does not allow other user to change or add data into the table when this Transaction Isolation Level is set to SERIALIZABLE...

```
CREATE Procedure usp_InsertSID
@SID varchar(225)

AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY

           IF @SID IS NULL
             RAISERROR('Validation Failed: SID is cannot be null', 16,1)

           IF EXISTS (SELECT SID from tableName
                        WHERE SID= @SID)
              RAISERROR('Validation Failed: SID already Exists',16,1)
        SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

          INSERT INTO tableName(ColumnNames)
          VALUES (@SID)

          COMMIT TRANSACTION
        SELECT @ReturnMessage = 'Sucess! New SID is added.'
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH 
       IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
         ROLLBACK TRAN

       SELECT  @ReturnMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()

          SELECT @ReturnCode AS ReturnCode, @ReturnMessage AS ReturnMessage,
                 ERROR_LINE()   AS ErrorLine,
                 ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
                 ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
    END CATCH
END

GO
```

Comment: I don't think that is safe. What if two threads execute in parallel? Both do not find the SID, then begin the transaction. One runs to add the new SID, commits, and then the other which was paused on the begin now runs. Am I missing something?